# Unexpected error in executing binary file from assembly code

Tags: bash, assembly, nasm

I have written a Hello world program in assembly.I compile the code using nasm

```
nasm -f elf64 -o Hello.o Hello.asm
```

The NASM compiling is successful and a object file is created. But when I link it using ld linker

```
ld -o Hello Hello.o
```

and then run it with `\. Hello`
this error occurs-
`bash: .:Hello: cannot execute binary file`

Comment: Don't `\. Hello`, but `./Hello`

Comment: @KshitijJoshi : What is the backslash supposed to do?  Also, you seem to have a space between the period and the `H`. This means that the command you effectively run here is `. Hello`, i.e. you try to _source_ a binary, which of course is not possible.